# General information about WPF and its XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, blend

1. What choice is the best one, coding or drop and click to generate xaml code?
2. If you are gonna work with visualization before doing coding or maybe doing both, should the process be taken in VS 2010 or Blend?
3. Is there any similiar code of WPF's C# WPF in other context for instance in Biztalk, sharepoint (except Winform) etc?
4. I heard that Microsoft Blend should be used for creating prototype only, is that true? Is Blend strong enough to work with user interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF makes it simple to separate the look&feel of the application and the logic behind. 
Blend is used to create styles, and may be used to create GUI prototypes. All this work however can be done in VS too. It's only a matter of convenience.

If you're using Visual Studio you can install Xaml power toys add-in which is able to do many different things for you (eg. generating DataGrid columns of a business form for an entity class)

> I heard that Microsoft Blend should be used for creating prototype only, is that true?

Blend is all about what you see. Vs is about the code.

> If you are gonna work with visualization before doing coding or maybe doing both, should the process be taken in VS 2010 or Blend?

Definitely blend.

> What choice is the best one, coding or drop and click to generate xaml code?

Doesn't matter. You do what's faster for you. I prefer typing, but someone else might prefer clicking.